# Handling CORS for subdomain ajax requests in rack

Tags: ajax, cors, rack, subdomain

After looking at other questions and answers I find they don't really cover want I want to do, hence why I'm asking a new question.

So, I built a subdomain matching middleware for rack with the idea that I would host my api in it's own subdomain (api.localhost:3000).

This for the most part works however if I try to send an ajax request the web browser throws a hissy fit about CORS.

So how do I add in CORS for subdomains for my Subdomain matching middleware bearing in mind I'm working in rack for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can prevent the use of CORS or jsonp I suggest you do. The best solution would be to define a subdirectory to handle your API/restful requests. I had a similar situation and when you force yourself into CORS aka Header Always Set Access-Control-Allow-Origin * then you set yourself up for limitations.

Avoid these limitations when possible. Just my experience. Good luck!

I would do something like:

http://www.domain.com/rest/api/items/1

Where rest is where your web services are handled. Get away from subdomains if you don't need them.

If you must absolutely use CORS and you know that requests are handled by you and only you then you can get away with using **jsonp**.

**jsonp**

jsonp essentially wraps your request in a javascript object using the callback function. There are limitations to the amount of data you can handle using this approach, but it is a quick way to get your cross domain requests to work without setting up CORS.

Here is an example of a jsonp request:

```
  $.ajax({
           type: "GET",
           url:  "http://www.domain.com/rest/WEB055S?callback=?",
           data: args,
           contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
           dataType: "jsonp"}).
           done(function(data){
               alert(data.ERROR);
           })...
```

Comment: Interesting, is the a way to do this without jquery?

Comment: There are some APIs available for PHP for cross domain that I know of but the CORS will still have to be set up. The jsonp is the only client-side hack that I know of, but if you only need server-side cross domain abilities then the browser doesn't have to know it is cross domain so that makes life alot easier. You should be able to setup `.htaccess` or `http.conf` with the allow all cross-origin directive and be good to go.

Comment: I just would hate to see you limited to server-side programming lol

Comment: Hmmm, whilst your answer doesn't exactly answer my question it's probably the closest to what I need. Any way, I don't intend to just do server side, I just wanted to expand my knowledge on subdomains and CORS and organise my API differently.

Comment: Right. That is why I am trying to send you down the right path. My shop started out with subdomains and it literally took me six months on figuring out how our IBMi server could handle CGI-scripts for server and client-side. It was a big mess. It literally came down to a directory directive. If you need any help setting up you server to handle both server-side and client-side requests feel free to contact me.